# BizTalk behaviour Http Send Adaptor when receiving a 400 or 500

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

If my Http Send adaptor receives an http 500 I want to retry.  If it returns a 400 I don't want it to retry.  Instead I want to subscribe to the message and email it somewhere.

It seems that the Http Send adaptor automatically retries in everything but a 200 and when it is a 400 or 500 does not appear to publish the response message.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is it's expected behaviour.  It is something I wrote about as a missing feature in my blog article [BizTalk 2013 R2 known bugs, issues & quirks](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/) (excerpt below), as there was also an issue with the way it throws the error after the retries have finished.  The workaround would be to set retries to zero and have an Orchestration or code another retry mechanism.

> MISSING: BIZTALK WCF-WEBHTTP ADAPTER ABILITY TO SUPPRESS 404 STATUS CODE

> Details: When you do a get on a RESTful service and get a 404 status code and a payload saying that the object you asked for does not exists, it will throw a SOAP exception.  It would be nice to be able to suppress a 404 status code (or other status codes) on a GET (or other operations) and to parse the response as normal through the pipeline and process as business exception rather than a System Exception.

> Work around: Catch the exception in an Orchestration and look for the not found error description that the service threw.